# Invalid identity escape WebpackEncore

Tags: regex, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, symfony5

I had working React app and now i migrating it inside symfony project. I have working webpack encore (tested with diferrent app) but still getting `SyntaxError: invalid identity escape in regular expression`
Using this babel config

```
    .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.plugins.push('transform-class-properties');
        babelConfig.plugins.push('transform-regexp-constructors');
        babelConfig.plugins.push('@babel/transform-unicode-regex');
    })
```

Some advice for newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding `includeNodeModules: ['camelcase']` to webpack.config.js. The module camelCase was the troublemaker.